# Python Kivy conditional Layout

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a Kivy application which will serve as a SmartMirror. The mirror is supposed to go into the main menu, which I already programmed, if a certain event fired, otherwise the screen should remain black. 
This means on that event I need to load all the body.kv file and after a certain timeout the body should be unloaded.

```
Builder.load_file('smartmirror.kv')
Builder.load_file('headerspace.kv')
Builder.load_file('bodyspace.kv')
Builder.load_file('footerspace.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = SmartMirrorApp()
    app.run()
```

How do I do this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html.

**ScreenManager** can manage your blank/main *screen transitions*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look into that. Besides do you know how I can make another Class running alongside Kivy? The FaceRecognizer class also has a run() method but when I call it afterwards app.run() of Kivy it simply does not execute.

Comment: You should post a another question on that with a minimal **working** example so it will be easier to help

Comment: Ok, I will. Thank you nethertheless.